# Why does the stream position go to the end

Tags: java, filestream, streamwriter

I have a csv file, after I overwrite 1 line with the Write method, after re-writing to the file everything is already added to the end of the file, and not to a specific line

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

public class LoadQuestion : MonoBehaviour
{
    int index;

    string path;

    FileStream file;

    StreamReader reader;

    StreamWriter writer;

    public Text City;

    public string[] allQuestion;

    public string[] addedQuestion;

    private void Start()
    {
        index = 0;

        path = Application.dataPath + "/Files/Questions.csv";

        allQuestion = File.ReadAllLines(path, Encoding.GetEncoding(1251));

        file = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite);

        writer = new StreamWriter(file, Encoding.GetEncoding(1251));

        reader = new StreamReader(file, Encoding.GetEncoding(1251));

        writer.AutoFlush = true;

        List<string> _questions = new List<string>();

        for (int i = 0; i < allQuestion.Length; i++)
        {
            char status = allQuestion[i][0];

            if (status == '0')
            {
                _questions.Add(allQuestion[i]);
            }
        }

        addedQuestion = _questions.ToArray();

        City.text = ParseToCity(addedQuestion[0]);
    }

    private string ParseToCity(string current)
    {
        string _city = "";

        string[] data = current.Split(';');

        _city = data[2];

        return _city;
    }


    private void OnApplicationQuit()
    {
        writer.Close();
        reader.Close();
        file.Close();
    }

    public void IKnow()
    {
        string[] quest = addedQuestion[index].Split(';');

        int indexFromFile = int.Parse(quest[1]);

        string questBeforeAnsver = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < quest.Length; i++)
        {
            if (i == 0)
            {
                questBeforeAnsver += "1";
            }
            else
            {
                questBeforeAnsver += ";" + quest[i];
            }
        }

        Debug.Log("indexFromFile : " + indexFromFile);

        for (int i = 0; i < allQuestion.Length; i++)
        {
            if (i == indexFromFile)
            {
                writer.Write(questBeforeAnsver);
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                reader.ReadLine();
            }
        }

        reader.DiscardBufferedData();

        reader.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        if (index < addedQuestion.Length - 1)
        {
            index++;
        }

        City.text = ParseToCity(addedQuestion[index]);
    }

}
```

There are lines in the file by type :

0;0;Africa
0;1;London
0;2;Paris

The bottom line is that this is a game, and only those questions whose status is 0, that is, unanswered, are downloaded from the file. And if during the game the user clicks that he knows the answer, then there is a line in the file and is overwritten, only the status is no longer 0, but 1 and when the game is repeated, this question will not load.

It turns out for me that the first question is overwritten successfully, and all subsequent ones are simply added at the end of the file :

1;0;Africa
0;1;London
0;2;Paris1;1;London1;2;Paris

What's wrong ?
[The video shows everything in detail](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GTk8083pkSB0MiGynhUY6S3SdDrFCGfA/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: you tag says it's java, i see it's C#?

Comment: Yes it c#......

Comment: if i understood correctly, you want to add new record on new line, 1. you can use @PrintWriter, which will print data on new line, 2. you can use escape character writer.Write("\n"+questBeforeAnsver); 3. you can append new data. writer.append(). so one and so one, there is many ways to do that. first try do write data with new line character.

Comment: Thank you, I thought that overwriting a line every time would be too unprofitable, so I just read the entire file first with the File.ReadAllLines method, and after playing just overwrite the same csv file with the File.WriteAllLines method

Comment: yes, that will work as well, it depends on your needs. approach can be many, according to specific requirements.